# Using derivative to estimate change overestimates change between two states

Tags: derivatives, mathematical-modeling, economics, optimal-control

I have a profit function in which revenue is given by the state of a variable y at each point in time t: R=y[t]-y[t]^2 and costs depend on the change in y from the previous state so that large changes are more costly C=(y[t]-y[t-1])^2.

[Edit for clarification: the model was originally given to me in discrete time as above. I changed it to continuous time by replacing the difference in the cost term with the derivative of y. After optimizing this, I got the optimal path of y as a continuous function] In this case, t goes from 0 to 2 and y is between 0.2 and 0.5. If I look at the values of the y points and the changes between them, the derivative is much larger than the actual change, depending on how small I set the time intervals (e.g. 0.1 or 0.01).

Because the derivative is much larger than the change, the costs explode and I get negative profits whereas if I calculate the change between the y the profits are always positive because changes are quite small.

Here is an example of what I am talking about, with p1 being calculated using the derivative and p2 using the change between y values:

```
   t    dy/dt   y(t)       p1     p2
0,00    0,60    0,20        
0,01    0,59    0,21    -0,20   0,16
0,02    0,57    0,21    -0,18   0,17
0,03    0,56    0,22    -0,16   0,17
0,04    0,54    0,22    -0,14   0,17
0,05    0,53    0,23    -0,12   0,18
0,06    0,52    0,23    -0,10   0,18
0,07    0,50    0,24    -0,09   0,18
0,08    0,49    0,24    -0,07   0,18
0,09    0,48    0,25    -0,06   0,19
0,10    0,47    0,25    -0,04   0,19
```

Am I totally off base using the derivative for this purpose? How can I include the rate of change in the cost function in a continuous model? Is the fact that I am going back and calculating profits using the discrete function the problem or is the use of the derivative?

If it is of any help, I am using optimal control theory to try to maximize the profit function using the rate of change as the control variable. The functions that I am using are the results of that procedure.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how you have a continuous function for $y$: `....and costs depend on the change in y from the previous state...` sounds very much like a discrete recursive function, in which case a derivative doesn't make much sense.  Could you clarify please?

Comment: You are right. The model was originally formulated in discrete time with y[t]-y[t-1]. I replaced this with the derivative of y to make a continuous time model.

Answer (score 1):

The way your problem is set up, the time dimension is discrete, and $y(t)$ apparently is continuous *at each $t$*, NOT from $t-1$ to $t$.

$$\pi_t = R_t - C_t = y_t-y_t^2 - (y_t-y_{t-1})^2 $$

For a continuous-time formulation it should be written

$$\pi(t) = R(t) - C(t) = y(t)-y(t)^2 - \dot y(t)^2 $$

Now *if* your problem is set up in continuous time, *and* you want to make specific numerical calculations, of course you will work with discrete intervals, where the value of the derivative should be approximated.  In that case, remember that $\frac {dy}{dt}$ is "the change in $y$ IF $t$ changes by 1" (so the denominator $dt=1$) - not by "one (arbitrary) unit". In your case, $t$ does not change by $1$ but by $0,01$.

Comment: Thank you for this. The problem was indeed originally formulated the way you put it and I had changed it to the continuous time version you presented when I attempted the optimization. So just to clarify: the problem isn't actually with the use of the derivative, but that I'm taking discrete intervals and those are actually incorrect?

Comment: Does your problem include a functional representation of $y$ _as a function of $t$_?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following continuous time representation where $R$ and $C$ represent **cumulative** revenues and costs:

$R(t)=R(0)+\int_0^t{\{y(\tau)-y(\tau)^2\}\mathrm{d}\tau}$

$C(t)=C(0)+\int_0^t{\{\mathrm{d}y(\tau)/\mathrm{d}\tau\}^2\mathrm{d}\tau}$

Since revenue and costs depend only on instantaneous $y$ and $\dot{y}$, this representation is economically more applealing but won't exactly reproduce the discrete time numbers, which assign special importance to integer values of $t$.

For solution in discrete time, here is an approach. A solution $y_n\equiv y(n)$ is optimal if changing $y_n$ to $y_n+\epsilon$ doesn't increase profit. That is,
$(y_n+\epsilon)-(y_n+\epsilon)^2-(y_{n+1}-y_n-\epsilon)^2-(y_n+\epsilon-y_{n-1})^2$ is maximized at $\epsilon=0$. The first order condition yields $y_n=(1+2y_{n+1}+2y_{n-1})/6$.

Replacing with $\{z_n\}\equiv\{y_n-0.5\}$ results in $z_{n+1}=3z_n-z_{n-1}$. This recurrence relation represents alternate terms in Fibbonacci series:

$F_{n+2}=F_{n+1}+F_{n}=2F_n+F_{n-1}=3F_n-F_{n-2}$.

With variable transformations, we can get $z_n=F_{2(n-1)}z_2-F_{2(n-2)}z_1$ for $n>1$ where $F_0=0,F_1=1$.

Suppose we want to maximize aggregate discounted profit with $\delta$ as discount factor. Aggregate discounted profit equals

$\sum{\delta^n[0.25-\{F_{2(n-1)}z_2-F_{2(n-2)}z_1\}^2]}-\sum{\delta^n\{(F_{2(n-1)}-F_{2(n-2)})z_2-(F_{2(n-2)}-F_{2(n-3)})z_1\}^2}$

Assume $F_{-1}=1$ in above. The first order condition for maximization with respect to $z_2$ is

$z_2=\frac{\sum{\delta^n[F_{2(n-1)}F_{2(n-2)}+\{F_{2(n-1)}-F_{2(n-2)}\}\{F_{2(n-2)}-F_{2(n-3)}\}]}}{\sum{\delta^n[F_{2(n-1)}^2+\{F_{2(n-1)}-F_{2(n-2)}\}^2]}}z_1$.

The optimal ratio $z_2/z_1$ equals $r=1/\phi^2=0.381966...$ where $\phi=1.618034...$ is the Golden ratio. Since $r$ satisfies the equation $r^2=3r-1$, the solution $z_{n+1}=3z_n-z_{n-1}$ simplifies to $z_n=r^{n-1}z_1$. Substituting given initial condition $y_1=0.2$ or equivalently $z_1=-0.3$ gives $y_n=0.5-0.3r^{n-1}$.

Note that we can skip a few steps once we get recurrence equation for $z_n$ by noting that the series should be a geometric series if the solution does not depend on time and all future $z$'s are proportional to $z_1$.

[image: Solution Plot]